# Larger gnuplot generated TikZ TeX does not compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I have generated using gnuplot a TikZ TeX script, and - unlike a simple `plot sin(x)`- it does not compile. What am I exactly missing?

The error message I receive when running `pdflatex` is

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/gnuplot' and I am going t
o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

My entire test file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\author{Rodion ``rodde'' Efremov}
\title{Trying to get the gnuplot generated TikZ TeX to compile}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
%% generated with GNUPLOT 5.0p5 (Lua 5.2; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
%% Thu Mar  9 13:27:03 2017
\tikzset{every node/.append style={font={Verdana\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}}}
\path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (850.000,500.000);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetdashtype{gp dt solid}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.806,2.088)--(1.986,2.088);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,2.088)--(849.156,2.088);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,2.088) {$0$};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,84.888)--(1.986,84.888);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,84.888)--(849.156,84.888);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,84.888) {$200$};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,167.688)--(1.986,167.688);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,167.688)--(849.156,167.688);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,167.688) {$400$};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,250.489)--(1.986,250.489);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,250.489)--(849.156,250.489);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,250.489) {$600$};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,333.289)--(1.986,333.289);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,333.289)--(849.156,333.289);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,333.289) {$800$};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,416.089)--(1.986,416.089);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,416.089)--(849.156,416.089);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,416.089) {$1000$};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,498.889)--(1.986,498.889);
\draw[gp path] (849.336,498.889)--(849.156,498.889);
\node[gp node right,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (1.585,498.889) {$1200$};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (78.854,1.867) {Binary};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (155.902,1.867) {Binomial};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (232.951,1.867) {Fibonacci};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (309.999,1.867) {Pairing};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (387.047,1.867) {Dial's};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (464.095,1.867) {AVL-tree};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (541.143,1.867) {vEB-tree};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (618.191,1.867) {B-tree, 32};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (695.240,1.867) {B-tree, 64};
\node[gp node left,rotate=-45,font={Monospaced},bold 14] at (772.288,1.867) {B-tree, 128};
\draw[gp path] (1.806,498.889)--(1.806,2.088)--(849.336,2.088)--(849.336,498.889)--cycle;
\node[gp node center,rotate=-270,font={Verdana\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (0.295,250.488) {Duration in milliseconds};
\node[gp node center,font={Verdana\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (425.571,499.444) {Other integer heap performance};
\node[gp node right,font={Verdana\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (847.609,498.524) {Unidexed};
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (847.830,498.432)--(848.894,498.432)--(848.894,498.617)--(847.830,498.617)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (847.830,498.432)--(848.894,498.432)--(848.894,498.616)--(847.830,498.616)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (50.924,2.088)--(68.261,2.088)--(68.261,96.067)--(50.924,96.067)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (50.924,2.088)--(50.924,96.066)--(68.260,96.066)--(68.260,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (127.972,2.088)--(145.309,2.088)--(145.309,95.653)--(127.972,95.653)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (127.972,2.088)--(127.972,95.652)--(145.308,95.652)--(145.308,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (205.021,2.088)--(222.357,2.088)--(222.357,102.691)--(205.021,102.691)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (205.021,2.088)--(205.021,102.690)--(222.356,102.690)--(222.356,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (282.069,2.088)--(299.406,2.088)--(299.406,98.965)--(282.069,98.965)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (282.069,2.088)--(282.069,98.964)--(299.405,98.964)--(299.405,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (359.117,2.088)--(376.454,2.088)--(376.454,75.781)--(359.117,75.781)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (359.117,2.088)--(359.117,75.780)--(376.453,75.780)--(376.453,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (436.165,2.088)--(453.502,2.088)--(453.502,79.507)--(436.165,79.507)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (436.165,2.088)--(436.165,79.506)--(453.501,79.506)--(453.501,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (513.213,2.088)--(530.550,2.088)--(530.550,418.574)--(513.213,418.574)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (513.213,2.088)--(513.213,418.573)--(530.549,418.573)--(530.549,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (590.261,2.088)--(607.598,2.088)--(607.598,78.679)--(590.261,78.679)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (590.261,2.088)--(590.261,78.678)--(607.597,78.678)--(607.597,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (667.310,2.088)--(684.647,2.088)--(684.647,85.717)--(667.310,85.717)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (667.310,2.088)--(667.310,85.716)--(684.646,85.716)--(684.646,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.333,0.333,1.000}} (744.358,2.088)--(761.695,2.088)--(761.695,79.093)--(744.358,79.093)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (744.358,2.088)--(744.358,79.092)--(761.694,79.092)--(761.694,2.088)--cycle;
\node[gp node right,font={Verdana\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont}] at (847.609,498.154) {Indexed};
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (847.830,498.062)--(848.894,498.062)--(848.894,498.247)--(847.830,498.247)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (847.830,498.062)--(848.894,498.062)--(848.894,498.246)--(847.830,498.246)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (70.186,2.088)--(87.523,2.088)--(87.523,90.271)--(70.186,90.271)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (70.186,2.088)--(70.186,90.270)--(87.522,90.270)--(87.522,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (147.234,2.088)--(164.571,2.088)--(164.571,101.863)--(147.234,101.863)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (147.234,2.088)--(147.234,101.862)--(164.570,101.862)--(164.570,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (224.283,2.088)--(241.619,2.088)--(241.619,110.557)--(224.283,110.557)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (224.283,2.088)--(224.283,110.556)--(241.618,110.556)--(241.618,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (301.331,2.088)--(318.668,2.088)--(318.668,105.175)--(301.331,105.175)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (301.331,2.088)--(301.331,105.174)--(318.667,105.174)--(318.667,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (378.379,2.088)--(395.716,2.088)--(395.716,91.099)--(378.379,91.099)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (378.379,2.088)--(378.379,91.098)--(395.715,91.098)--(395.715,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (455.427,2.088)--(472.764,2.088)--(472.764,93.583)--(455.427,93.583)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (455.427,2.088)--(455.427,93.582)--(472.763,93.582)--(472.763,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (532.475,2.088)--(549.812,2.088)--(549.812,446.726)--(532.475,446.726)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (532.475,2.088)--(532.475,446.725)--(549.811,446.725)--(549.811,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (609.524,2.088)--(626.860,2.088)--(626.860,79.093)--(609.524,79.093)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (609.524,2.088)--(609.524,79.092)--(626.859,79.092)--(626.859,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (686.572,2.088)--(703.909,2.088)--(703.909,89.857)--(686.572,89.857)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (686.572,2.088)--(686.572,89.856)--(703.908,89.856)--(703.908,2.088)--cycle;
\gpfill{rgb color={0.957,0.863,0.259}} (763.620,2.088)--(780.957,2.088)--(780.957,84.061)--(763.620,84.061)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (763.620,2.088)--(763.620,84.060)--(780.956,84.060)--(780.956,2.088)--cycle;
\draw[gp path] (1.806,498.889)--(1.806,2.088)--(849.336,2.088)--(849.336,498.889)--cycle;
%% coordinates of the plot area
\gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{1.806cm}{2.088cm}}{\pgfpoint{849.336cm}{498.889cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
%% gnuplot variables

\end{document}
```

The above snippet was generated by the following gnuplot script:

```
set terminal tikz size 850,500 enhanced font 'Verdana,12' persist
set output "integer_heap_benchmark_other_tikz.tex"
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set ylabel "Duration in milliseconds" #font "Arial 14"
set tics font "Monospaced,bold 14"
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox 
set style histogram cluster gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set minussign
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45 autojustify
set xtics norangelimit
set xtics    ()
set title "Other integer heap performance"
set yrange [0:*]
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "#000000"
set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb "green"
plot 'integer_heap_benchmark_other.dat' using 2:xtic(1) linecolor rgb "#5555ff" title col, \
        '' using 3:xtic(1) linecolor rgb "#f4dc42" title col, \
        '' using 4:xtic(1) title col
```

Comment: First of all it is always a good idea to cite the error you get. Plus people here are generally not happy about code hosted externally, that data might not be available in the future.

Comment: @daleif Fair enough. I will try to improve my question asap.

Comment: @daleif I added the error message. How should I go about presenting my code?

Comment: Do the same thing. Paste it into the editor here. Tip: if you mark the code and click CTRL-k then the editor will indent this region 4 spaces displaying it as code (I think the editor controls an also do this).

Comment: The error indicate the `gnuplot` key/style is unknown. I have no idea what it should be.

Comment: The `gnuplot` manual will tell you that you need to add `\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Unfortunately `\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}` passes, yet leads to other errors.

Comment: I hope you don't expect me to be able guess the cause of "other errors" ...  I understand that the file `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` is also generated by Gnuplot, can you add that to your question as well?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I use gnuplot 5.0.5, and there is no mention of `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` in its documentation and none is generated.

Comment: Well, the `.sty` is not mentioned explicitly, but `\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}` is mentioned on page 215 of http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf, and a bit further up on the page, under the description of `charsize`, it says "Look at the generated style file [...]". Which was the reason for my assumption.

Comment: Anyway, you must have `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty` if that `\usepackage` doesn't give an error, but we cannot diagnose unknown error messages (which error *did* you get?). Would showing the Gnuplot code itself, so we can try that, be a possibility for you?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Gnuplot script added. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55062/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-coderodde).

Answer (score 1):

(In case anyone else wonders how to make this work.)

Take a simpler Gnuplot script such as this:

```
set terminal tikz size 5,4 createstyle
set output "demo.tex"
plot sin(x)
```

Compared to your script, there is one key thing that is added:

```
createstyle
```

That option means that some additional files are created, as seen from the terminal output shown below. These files contain the style definitions that are used in the TikZ code.

```
plots$ ls
tikzout.gnu
plots$ gnuplot tikzout.gnu 
plots$ ls
demo.tex                     gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty  t-gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex
gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex  gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex  tikzout.gnu
```

The various files contains code for LaTeX (`gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty`), ConTeXt (`t-gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex`) and plain TeX (`gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex`).

A minimal LaTeX document for using the Gnuplot output will then be

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\begin{document}
\input{demo}
\end{document}
```

The generated `gnuplot-lua-tikz` loads the TikZ package (hence `\usepackage{tikz}` not required), and defines all  the necessary styles. The output of this is

[image: output of code]

(Not the prettiest plot, but this was just a demonstration anyway.)

For reference, the `demo.tex` file generated by Gnuplot looks like the following.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
%% generated with GNUPLOT 5.0p3 (Lua 5.1; terminal rev. 99, script rev. 100)
%% Sat 25 Nov 2017 07:02:18 PM CET
\path (0.000,0.000) rectangle (5.000,4.000);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\gpsetlinetype{gp lt border}
\gpsetdashtype{gp dt solid}
\gpsetlinewidth{1.00}
\draw[gp path] (1.196,0.616)--(1.376,0.616);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,0.616)--(4.267,0.616);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,0.616) {$-1$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,0.918)--(1.376,0.918);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,0.918)--(4.267,0.918);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,0.918) {$-0.8$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,1.219)--(1.376,1.219);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,1.219)--(4.267,1.219);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,1.219) {$-0.6$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,1.520)--(1.376,1.520);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,1.520)--(4.267,1.520);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,1.520) {$-0.4$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,1.822)--(1.376,1.822);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,1.822)--(4.267,1.822);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,1.822) {$-0.2$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,2.124)--(1.376,2.124);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,2.124)--(4.267,2.124);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,2.124) {$0$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,2.425)--(1.376,2.425);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,2.425)--(4.267,2.425);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,2.425) {$0.2$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,2.727)--(1.376,2.727);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,2.727)--(4.267,2.727);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,2.727) {$0.4$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,3.028)--(1.376,3.028);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,3.028)--(4.267,3.028);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,3.028) {$0.6$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,3.330)--(1.376,3.330);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,3.330)--(4.267,3.330);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,3.330) {$0.8$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,3.631)--(1.376,3.631);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,3.631)--(4.267,3.631);
\node[gp node right] at (1.012,3.631) {$1$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,0.616)--(1.196,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (1.196,3.631)--(1.196,3.451);
\node[gp node center] at (1.196,0.308) {$-10$};
\draw[gp path] (2.009,0.616)--(2.009,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (2.009,3.631)--(2.009,3.451);
\node[gp node center] at (2.009,0.308) {$-5$};
\draw[gp path] (2.822,0.616)--(2.822,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (2.822,3.631)--(2.822,3.451);
\node[gp node center] at (2.822,0.308) {$0$};
\draw[gp path] (3.634,0.616)--(3.634,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (3.634,3.631)--(3.634,3.451);
\node[gp node center] at (3.634,0.308) {$5$};
\draw[gp path] (4.447,0.616)--(4.447,0.796);
\draw[gp path] (4.447,3.631)--(4.447,3.451);
\node[gp node center] at (4.447,0.308) {$10$};
\draw[gp path] (1.196,3.631)--(1.196,0.616)--(4.447,0.616)--(4.447,3.631)--cycle;
\node[gp node right] at (2.979,3.297) {sin(x)};
\gpcolor{rgb color={0.580,0.000,0.827}}
\draw[gp path] (3.163,3.297)--(4.079,3.297);
\draw[gp path] (1.196,2.944)--(1.229,2.673)--(1.262,2.380)--(1.295,2.077)--(1.327,1.776)%
  --(1.360,1.488)--(1.393,1.227)--(1.426,1.002)--(1.459,0.823)--(1.492,0.696)--(1.524,0.628)%
  --(1.557,0.620)--(1.590,0.674)--(1.623,0.787)--(1.656,0.953)--(1.689,1.168)--(1.721,1.421)%
  --(1.754,1.703)--(1.787,2.002)--(1.820,2.306)--(1.853,2.603)--(1.886,2.880)--(1.918,3.126)%
  --(1.951,3.332)--(1.984,3.488)--(2.017,3.589)--(2.050,3.630)--(2.083,3.610)--(2.115,3.530)%
  --(2.148,3.392)--(2.181,3.203)--(2.214,2.969)--(2.247,2.702)--(2.280,2.411)--(2.313,2.108)%
  --(2.345,1.806)--(2.378,1.517)--(2.411,1.252)--(2.444,1.023)--(2.477,0.839)--(2.510,0.707)%
  --(2.542,0.632)--(2.575,0.618)--(2.608,0.666)--(2.641,0.772)--(2.674,0.934)--(2.707,1.144)%
  --(2.739,1.394)--(2.772,1.674)--(2.805,1.971)--(2.838,2.276)--(2.871,2.573)--(2.904,2.853)%
  --(2.936,3.103)--(2.969,3.313)--(3.002,3.475)--(3.035,3.581)--(3.068,3.629)--(3.101,3.615)%
  --(3.133,3.540)--(3.166,3.408)--(3.199,3.224)--(3.232,2.995)--(3.265,2.730)--(3.298,2.441)%
  --(3.330,2.139)--(3.363,1.836)--(3.396,1.545)--(3.429,1.278)--(3.462,1.044)--(3.495,0.855)%
  --(3.528,0.717)--(3.560,0.637)--(3.593,0.617)--(3.626,0.658)--(3.659,0.759)--(3.692,0.915)%
  --(3.725,1.121)--(3.757,1.367)--(3.790,1.644)--(3.823,1.941)--(3.856,2.245)--(3.889,2.544)%
  --(3.922,2.826)--(3.954,3.079)--(3.987,3.294)--(4.020,3.460)--(4.053,3.573)--(4.086,3.627)%
  --(4.119,3.619)--(4.151,3.551)--(4.184,3.424)--(4.217,3.245)--(4.250,3.020)--(4.283,2.759)%
  --(4.316,2.471)--(4.348,2.170)--(4.381,1.867)--(4.414,1.574)--(4.447,1.303);
\gpcolor{color=gp lt color border}
\draw[gp path] (1.196,3.631)--(1.196,0.616)--(4.447,0.616)--(4.447,3.631)--cycle;
%% coordinates of the plot area
\gpdefrectangularnode{gp plot 1}{\pgfpoint{1.196cm}{0.616cm}}{\pgfpoint{4.447cm}{3.631cm}}
\end{tikzpicture}
%% gnuplot variables
```